# Flask to Django conversion

Tags: python, django

Flask project

html code

```
<a href="{{ url_for('flight', flight_id=flight.id) }}">
```

python code

```
@app.route("/flights/<int:flight_id>")
def flight(flight_id):
```

I want to convert the above piece of code into corresponding Django form. Inside Django project in views.py file `def flight(request)` is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `urls.py` file add the route

```
urlpatterns = [
[..]

    path('flights/<int:flight_id>', views.flight, name='flight'),

[..]
```

in `views.py` add your function based view (FBV) to make thing simple

```
def flight(request, flight_id):
    [..]
```

in you template add your route like

```
<a href="{% url 'flight' flight_id=flight.id %}"></a>
```